# Do the scriptures indicate the physical appearance of the Israelites?

Tags: israel

I have seen ancient depictions of the ancient Israelites and there features were different than I expected.

Linguistic experts have stated that Hebrew is one of the early Asiatic-African languages.

The Hamitic people were a dark skinned people, Noah's wife was Hamitic, moses' wife was Hamitic, the ancient Israelites mixed with Hamitic Egyptians for centuries before exodus.

In Acts 21:37-38 the soldier mistakenly took Paul for a Hamitic Egyptian. How could the soldier mistake Paul for an Egyptian unless the ancient Israelites were of a darker skin tone?

Is there any references in Scripture to the physical identity of the ancient Israelites?

Comment: How can Noah's wife be Hamitic when she gave birth to Ham??

Comment: I was told that Noah's wife was identified with him in a sense of pigmentation

Comment: By who? There's no information about that in the Bible. Sounds like pure speculation.

Comment: Those are some theories but they're not universally accepted. Ham is also likely the ancestor of many nations including the Chinese for example.

Comment: While it may not be strictly off-topic here, this is probably a better question for History.SE.

Comment: @Flimzy Or if there is an anthropology.se.

Comment: Unless you explain what it is that you expected, how can your question be answered? Do you expect Israelites (that is sooo good) to be darker than modern Israelis? There are clear depictions (one reasonably sure of Israelites) of people from that period and era and there is no reason to believe they look any different to modern Israelis. That is a wide mix of racial characteristics. Maybe explain your question more clearly.

Comment: Solomon was black. I will find the Scripture which he states this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will literally never know without a time machine. However, given the region and it's history, as well as the people living there today it's reasonable to assert that they were a mix of all types of skin tones ranging from the typical Israeli today to the darker toned Northern African people today.

The closest example to a "typical" Hamitic person is [this picture of a Bashirin Hamite](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/be/MPP-Hm1.jpg) from Augustus Henry Keane's *Man, Past and Present* (1899). So if you went with Keane's findings, that'd be your closest answer. However, as I mentioned above, it's not unreasonable to assume they were the typical Israeli/Northern African tone.

Comment: @Jesse. Have you ever seen an Israeli? Do you mean Israelite? Typical 'tone'? What are you talking about? Bad answer.

Comment: Half of this makes sense. Half of it is meaningless strings of words. The phrase "typical Israeli/Northern African tone" conveys no meaning unless you meant to say in effect "Yellow. No blue!"

Answer (score -1):

> There is a strong tradition that some of the descendants of Noah
>   through his son Ham were black. Ham had a son named Cush, which means
>   "black" in Hebrew. Cush is the most common term designating color in
>   reference to persons, people or lands used in the Bible. It’s used 58
>   times in the King James Version. The Greek and Latin word is Ethiopia.
>   In classical literature, Greek and Roman authors describe Ethiopians
>   as black. Archaeology has found these people to be black. In the book
>   of Jeremiah, the question is asked, "Can the Ethiopian change his
>   skin?"
>
> Genesis 10:6-20 describes the descendants of Ham as being located in
>   North Africa, Central Africa and in parts of southern Asia. Psalm
>   105:23 mentions the "land of Ham" in Egypt, and Psalm 78:51 connects
>   the "tents of Ham" with Egypt.

I'm going to write this answer from top of my head. It's not unreasonable to believe this theory. If we take in consideration scripture that describes Ancient of Days (name Daniel used for God) having hair like wool. Or in revelations similar description: "The hair of His head was white like wool, as white as snow, and His eyes were like a blazing fire." referring to Yeshua... key clue is wooly head which is of course typical "African" (for lack of better term) feature. If we look at ancient archaeology we can conclude that ancient B.C. civilisations like Sumer, Babylon, Akkadian, Hattites, 'Israel', and others had darker complexion... even ancient Chinese etc.

So how did the current Jews some to Israel and no trace of darker complexion?

Well answer is diaspora, exile and numerous ethnic cleansing and wars on the Jews etc...

This is even in scriptures all over the place.

This is why now we have various African Jewish tribes claiming to be "original jews"...

> Genetic tests carried out by British scientists have revealed that
>   many of the Lemba tribesmen in southern Africa have Jewish origins,
>   according to a report by the BBC. The Lemba, a tribe of 70,000 to
>   80,000 members who live in central Zimbabwe and northern South Africa,
>   have customs which are similar to Jewish ones: Lemba refrain from
>   eating pork or other foods forbidden by the Torah, or forbidden
>   combinations of permitted foods, wear yarmulke-like skull caps,
>   conduct ritual animal slaughter, have a holy day once a week, and even
>   put a Star of David on their gravestones. According to their oral
>   tradition, the Lemba are descended from seven Jewish men who left
>   Israel 2,500 years ago and married African women, according to the
>   BBC. The Lemba prefer their children to marry other Lembas, and
>   marriage to non-Lembas is being discouraged.
>
> Their sacred prayer language is a mixture of Hebrew and Arabic. Their
>   religious artifact is a replica of the Biblical Ark of the Covenant
>   known as the ‘ngoma lungundu’, meaning "the drum that thunders.” The
>   object went on display recently at a museum in Harare, Zimbabwe, and
>   has instilled pride in many of the Lemba. They say the ark was built
>   almost 700 years ago from the remains of the original ark, which
>   according to the Bible was used to store the Ten Commandments. For
>   decades, the ancient vessel was thought to be lost until it was
>   discovered in a storeroom in Harare recently.
>
> Members of the priestly clan of the Lemba, the Buba – which is one of
>   12 clans – have a genetic element also found among the Jewish priestly
>   line, known as Kohanim. "This was amazing," Professor Tudor Parfitt
>   from the University of London told the BBC. "It looks as if the Jewish
>   priesthood continued in the West by people called Cohen, and in same
>   way it was continued by the priestly clan of the Lemba.”

It's not that crazy if you study the history IMO...

There is a lot of correlation between Hebrew customs and African customs of West Africa for example, you have Books like "Hebrewisms of West Africa: From Nile to Niger with the Jews" that describe this.

> In 1930 the Dial Press of New York published a book by Joseph J.
>   Williams entitled Hebrewisms of West Africa: From Nile to Niger with
>   the Jews. Williams was a Catholic friar who devoted several years in
>   Jamaica studying the Ashanti. In his observations, he noted remarkable
>   evidence of Hebraic culture amongst them.
>
> He indicates quite interestingly that, “The very name Ashanti has
>   itself a strong Hebraic flavor. For, while some would derive the word
>   from ‘Shan’ the name of a plant, and ‘dti,’ to eat, claiming that the
>   title must have been acquired in the time of great famine, when they
>   found sustenance in the plan in question, this is mere quesswork.
>   Actually, the termination of “ti” or “tie” in the names of West
>   African Tribes has usually the general meaning of ‘the race of,’ ‘the
>   men of,’ ‘the children of.’ This would make Ashanti, ‘the people of
>   Ashan.’ There was as a fact, a town of the name Ashan in the domain of
>   Juda. Priests were in residence there according to the First Book of
>   Chronicles, where the word is spelt ASHAN though in the corresponding
>   passage of Joshua it is spelt AIN, which the Jewish Encyclopedia
>   suggests ‘may be a corruption of Ashan.’” (pp. 60-61)
>   ***Note: See 1 Chronicles 6:59 and Joshua 21:16 for the Scriptural references.***
>
> Williams also notes a “truly remarkable similarity of the Ashanti Yame
>   and the Hebrew Yahweh, first as regards the etymological derivation of
>   the words themselves; and then in the tribal concept of Divine
>   Attributes and the created channels of Divine influence; and finally
>   in the divided service.” (p.320) The Ashanti also believed in a
>   Redeemer whose name was Ta Kora, the “son of the supreme God.” (p.320)
>   Not all Jews are anti-Christ but to the contrary, the true Jews
>   acknowledge Moshiach as being identified as Yeshua.
>
> Hebrewisms were not just limited to the Ashanti in Jamaica but were
>   plentiful in the land from which they came: Africa. Williams notes the
>   following irrefutable evidence of Hebrewisms in Africa: 
>   • The Floggings, the traditional number of strokes: forty less one 
>   • The common practice of New Moon festivals • The oath drink • The
>   expectation of a Moshiach • Jewish distinction between diaboli and
>   demonia • The duodecimal division of tribes into families • Exogamy •
>   Blood sacrifices with the sprinkling of blood upon the altar and
>   door-posts • Mourning Customs • Obsessions • Legal defilement • Jewish
>   octave • Law on adultery • Sabbath rest • Levirate marriages •
>   Circumcision • Priestly garb

Today there are numerous "Hebrew Isrealite" movements that claim that original jews were indeed darker complexion.

It's still very controversial because of classical icon of Jesus in Roman Catholic church.

But also let's take in consideration Eastern orthodox or Ethiopian orthodox churches their iconography shows darker "Jesus/Yeshua" and old Ethiopian story of how they became Jewish/Christian goes that son of Solomon and Queen of Sheba went south and started Ethiopian empire.

Ethiopia has one of the oldest churches and even claims to have ark of the covenant maybe we should look into their traditions and knowledge to learn what they have to say and not only look at Roman Catholic perspective and imagery.

> The Solomonic dynasty, also known as the House of Solomon, is the
>   former ruling Imperial House of the Ethiopian Empire. The dynasty's
>   members claim patrilineal descent from the biblical King Solomon and
>   the Queen of Sheba. Tradition asserts that the Queen gave birth to
>   Menelik I after her biblically described visit to Solomon in
>   Jerusalem.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOrbz.jpg) In 1270, the Zagwe dynasty of Ethiopia was overthrown by
>   Yekuno Amlak, who claimed descent from Solomon and initiated the
>   Solomonic era of Ethiopia. The dynasty would last until 1974, ended by
>   a coup d'état and deposition of the emperor Haile Selassie.

[image: This image shows Jews being taken to Babylonian captivity]

This first image shows Jews being taken to Babylonian captivity

> The blackness of the ancient Hebrews has been vehemently denied by
>   most historians and lay people. Most Jews do not want to acknowledge
>   this truth because of what it means regarding the present day Jewish
>   population. The images in this document prove that the ancient Hebrews
>   were black. Notice the kinky short afros in some pictures, the dread
>   locks of the Hebrews, the brown complexion of
>   skin, and the African facial features of the Hebrews in the pictures.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Siege of Lachish:

[image]
[image]

Detail of the Assyrian conquest of the Jewish fortified town of Lachish (battle 701 BC). Part of a relief from the palace of Sennacherib at Niniveh

Comment: This answer starts poorly by trying to get any information about the physical appearance of Jesus from the highly stylised and metaphoric images of Revelation.

Comment: Well we can agree on that part what about the rest of the post?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour).

For more on what this site is all about, see: [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808/20394).
+1 for providing a different point of view from the usual among Christians of European stock, even if the issue is a hotly debated one.
Meanwhile, I hope you'll browse some of the other questions and answers on this site.

Comment: However, your answer would be much improved if you provided identification and references for all of your quotes and images. See:  [What makes a good supported answer?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/692/20394)

Comment: I will try to update my answer with proper references and scriptural evidence supporting this theory.

Comment: Why would they use word wool tho?

Comment: Whoever negatively down-voted this post shows the biased nature of this portal.